# how to return user email on google api, python

Tags: python, email, google-api, python-3.10

ive been trying to use google sheets api for a project and for this project it requires the users email to be compaired to a list of emails in the sheets and only return the rows with the users email in.

so if the google sheets as

A _______________________ B

personA@gmail.com ___apples

personB@gmail.con ___ bananas

personC@gmail.com __ oranges

and you log into the app using personB@gmail.com then the code returns bananas, without returning apples and oranges because those are associated with other emails.
but I haven't been able to get the email that the user authenticated with to return. and most other solutions where either too old and couldn't run on modern python (3.4.10) or where in different languages entirely. and I don't want to have to have the user enter their email twice.

I have code that I've attempted to use but its mostly irrelevant as the fixes to make it function in modern python make it not function for retrieving the users email after the oauth2.0 process.

Comment: Can you edit your question and an [example] first off how you are requesting authorization of the user.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend a bit on what scope you authorized the user with.  Assuming that you authorized them with one of the drive scopes.

You can go though the google drive api the [about.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get) method this will return the email address of the currently authenticated user.

```
"kind": "drive#about",
  "user": {
    "kind": "drive#user",
    "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
    "me": true,
    "permissionId": "437243",
    "emailAddress": "xxxx@gmail.com"
  },
```

If you have authorized the user with say the profile and email scopes then you could go though the google people api.  The [person.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) method